# Body Background Color Based on Pixels

Tags: html, css, background-color

Is it possible to stack one color on top of another color in the body background to match content within a container?

For example, if I know my header is 300 pixels tall, and is red, have the background set to red for the first 300pixels, then set the background to match the color of the rest of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jw60660; you do it with `background-image` poperty but not with `background-color` but you can do like this:

```
body{
    background:green;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body:after{
    background:yellow;
    content:"";
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display:block;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/TrZ9u/1/

Comment: @jw60660 I'd just like to point out that as it is... this doesn't work in ie7 and below.

Comment: there is typo in css "psotion"

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible by wrapping the header in a 100% width container with a background colour

```
body { background: green; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.header { width: 100%; height: 300px; background: yellow; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5KxJS/3/